# Check which side one rectangle collide with other

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics

I'm making a game somewhat like Breakout. Consider a scene when a small moving rectangle collides with a big fixed one.

[image: demostration]

You see that which direction the small rectangle will be bounced to depends on which side of the big rectangle it collides with (bottom, or left). With the same collision rectangle (red), how to distinguish the two case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have answered the question with your own diagram.

Perfectly elastic bounces don't depend on the nature of the intersection. They depend on the direction(s) of motion and the tangent at the point of contact (also angular velocity if they're rotating).

With axis-aligned rectangles moving parallel to the axes, the tangent is always at right angles (90 degrees) from the direction of motion.

Even if motion isn't parallel to the axes (you didn't say whether that's the case, only implied it), you need only to determine which surfaces made first contact. This is easy to do based on the velocity vector and two intersection displacements. Just calculate the two times in the past that the rectangles would have made contact on both x- and y-axes. The earlier time is the one you need.

Comment: _Just calculate the two times in the past that the rectangles would have made contact on both x- and y-axes._ I had thought up this by myself but doubt and you help me confirm it so thank u. I found much information here, how about the related? Can you recommend me some books or links? please.

Comment: This is a terrific one, imo: https://www.amazon.es/Game-Physics-David-H-Eberly/dp/0123749034  Expensive, but worth it. A lot of free stuff on the web is incomplete or even outright wrong. Eberly is rigorous and clear, though you do need calculus to get full benefit. Calculus scares some people away. Don't be one of them. You'll need it to get much farther than you currently are in any event.

Comment: Agree. I learned calculus before and now maybe I should have a review. But I found lots of old games seems using simplifed ways to determine collision reaction.For an example, check [this](https://github.com/city41/breakouts/blob/master/breakouts/frigame/breakout/ball.js#L109). Numerical methods and tricks are used for real-time performance. Thanks again, anyway.